# Running a mixed effect logistic regression with longitudinal data in R

Tags: r, regression, logistic, mixed-model, panel-data

I have access to data from primary care with a diagnosis of chronic renal disease (and no stroke) and blood pressure readings taken at irregular times (some patients may have a single reading, while some may have 3-4 readings a year) and dates of first stroke. I want to examine the association with systolic blood pressure (I will include other risk factors as well). I have reworked the data to look like this (time is days from renal disease to blood pressure).

| patient id | systolic blood pressure | stroke date | renal disease date | time | stroke | gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23244334 | 140 | 23-12-2007 | 20-12-2005 | 100 | 1 | 1 |
| 23244334 | 160 | 23-12-2007 | 20-12-2005 | 300 | 1 | 1 |
| 124334 | 135 | NA | 10-08-2007 | 200 | 0 | 0 |
| 447 | 170 | NA | 03-03-2011 | 10 | 0 | 0 |

My first through was to follow a mixed model with stroke as the outcome, gender as a fixed effect and blood pressure as the random slope.
Within R I would write the following after centering the data:

```
Model_Multi_Full <- glmer(stroke ~ gender + (1 + blood pressure|patid),
                          family = "binomial",
                          data = mydata)
```

However, I realised that it did not consider the time element of the readings (thus gradient of blood pressure ascent or descent). Is there a way to incorporate this?

Comment: If you include a random slope, your model should always have a correponding fixed slope.

Comment: You need to draw a variogram or other diagnostic to check the goodness of fit of the correlation pattern with the pattern induced by a random slopes model.  I don’t think an adequate fit is likely.  See [this](https://fharrell.com/post/re) and [this](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/markov).

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go for an interaction element of blood pressure with time. You can go for  `blood pressure * time` or (in my view and considering your question, the best way) `interaction(blood pressure, time)`.

If you want to include blood pressure as fixed effect, I'd say to follow the same structure.